# Is it possible to register an application in FCM servers using an API(URL) call

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

I want to register my application in FCM servers using an API(URL) call by passing package name and SHA key as parameters for every new application. Through this API call I want to download/create the google-services.json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a way to automate application registration in FCM / [Google developer APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/). I guess there's no way to do that.